# Bounty - Page 1 & 2 Differences

Tags: discussion, bounties, pagination, time-limit

In asking a few bounty questions I've noticed that the average page views per hour on page 1 is about **8x higher** than on page 2 (small sample based on a 2 of my questions, but I'm sure the large disparity remains true for most bounty questions now that there's a consistent queue over 50 questions).

This is a wiki for collective comments/ideas, what can you guys/girls come up with that would make the bounty system more useful?  In the current state your bounty is worth less the more questions it's behind times the time they have remaining, keeping it off page 1.

**The time your question spends in bounty mode before it reaches page 1 is significantly less likely to receive a useful answer.**  What would you do to better present bounty questions, increasing the exposure to people who might answer them from when they're marked while retaining some order of least-time-left at the top?

Related:  Are the paging controls just not that visible, are they being looked over and that's the reason page 2 and on are missed?

Comment: Do you realise how much effort it takes to click "Next page"?

Comment: @random: evidently, too much :)

Answer (score 6):

The [default Featured (bounty) tab on home page](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) is sorted in "soonest-to-end" order.

The home page displays 48 questions by default; right now there are 75 featured questions.

- The question on the BOTTOM (#48) has a bounty ending in 5 days.
- The question on the TOP (#1) has a bounty ending in 13 hours.

So, assuming this is typical, your question will have at *least* 5 days on the first page. Is this really a problem?

Comment: It would only become more of a problem as the site grows.  Say you grow to 4 pages of questions, it that case it's more likely that the question sees less than 2 days on the front page, the problem is proportional to the number of bounty questions active.  I agree it's not a large one now, but will become greater the more questions rack up....on the flip side, maybe I'm completely wrong, and the increased traffic/questions means more people to answer them as well, alleviating the queue.

Comment: I'm curious on your opinion of this, has it changed any?  I agree it's still not much on an issue currently, as most bounty questions seem to be getting answers.  I ask because the bottom question on the featured page now has 2 days, so the situation did change a bit since this question was posted.

Comment: @nick if you mouse over the "n days" part of the bounty message you can see the actual start dates. Right now the bottom-most bounty was started on 8-19 11:30 UTC, and the current time is 8-22 14:40 UTC. We've also doubled the # of questions (and thus bounties) shown on the home page since then. Remember I said 48 above.. count now and see!

Comment: Ahh, I think my confusion comes from the links, when I click "featured" I get 50 per page, this url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions then click featured tab, it's whatever your preference is, 50 per page for me.  Your link from the homepage doesn't limit to 50: http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured How do *most* users navigate to the featured section?  Is there a way to quickly tell? I'm not sure what kind of visit data is even stored with hit counts of this magnitude.

Comment: Currently, a featured question on StackOverflow gets may be half to one day on the front page of the bounty. Till then it almost gets no attention. I think the bounty system has to be re-designed for SO

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion could be to sort the bounties "randomly" - so you get them in some order, but not always the same.

Comment: don't care for that in this case, since the bounty should get more "urgent" closer to the end of the bounty period, exactly like eBay auctions -- most of the bidding is near the end when the default "ending soonest" search floats it to the top.