# Bountied questions sorted by "ending" should show bounties that are ending soonest at the top

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, new-nav

I noticed when viewing bountied questions, the ones with bounties ending the soonest are at the bottom of the list.

Can this be reversed so bounties ending soonest are at the top of the list?

[image]

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24089/bounty-page-1-2-differences/24099#24099) (admittedly quite old) claims that thos questions are  sorted in "soonest-to-end" order by default.

Comment: But basically the same thing is said in the [faq post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067): *Questions in that tab are sorted by the amount of time left on their bounties. The closer a bounty is to expiring, the higher it will be on the list.*

Comment: @Martin Yes, that is the expected sort, and the default sorting of the old navigation's "Featured" tab, so I would expect it to be applied to the new navigation too. I even recall counting on that kind of sorting back when I did a bit of bounty hunting of my own :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed, and will be deployed in the next build.